# Как создать SearchView в ToolBar без создания новой активити?

Tags: java, android, android-search-view

Вроде простая задача, а почему то не удается ее выполнить.

1. Создаю пункт в меню ToolBar :

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
           android:id="@+id/top_menu_search"
           android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
           app:showAsAction="always"
           android:title="@string/search_title" />
      <item
      ..../>
      <item
      ..../>
   </menu>
   ```
2. В активити

   ```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.top_menu_search);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   if(null!=searchManager ) {
   searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
   }
   ```

После этого выпадает Exseption ((

Подскажите, что дальше делать? 
Вопрос 1. Как сделать, чтобы это `SearchView` по нажатию реаировало как `SearchView`?
Вопрос 2. Что такое Search Manager?
Вопрос 3: Какие методы мне нужно переписать?

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
Тут я реагирую на окончание ввода и нажати кнопки поиск
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
Тут я реагирую на изменение текста в строке ввода SearchView
                return false;
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую вам Toolbar v7, информации по нему очень много в иментернете. Внутрь него посещаете SearchView и все ваши проблемы будут нужны. Все шаблоны в Android Studio по умолчанию в layout используют toolbar v7.